# Why does ShowMessage give unexpected output when my string contains #0 characters?

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Today I stumbled upon something mysterious. This line of code:

```
showmessage(menuMain.player[2] + ' ready!');
```

Generates this message (For example menuMain.player[2] = Player):

> Player

But if I put code this way (For example menuMain.player[2] = Player):

```
showmessage('Test: ' + menuMain.player[2]);
```

It will generate this message:

> Test: Player

According to the debugger, the exact value of the string `(buffer := menuMain.player[2] + ' ready!')` is this:

> 'Player'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0' ready!'

I do honestly believe this is a compiler glitch, because I have the *exact* same line in another block of code, and it works flawlessly.

Now the tough part for me, is that me being dumb, or this is indeed a glitch?

Comment: What is your declaration of `menuMain`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce this  issue.

Comment: @MartynA menuMain is a main form of the project, player is array[1..2] of string.

Comment: @KenWhite Hello again! ;) The Problem is that I can not reproduce this problem on the new project. Everything is fine there, the only way is to share a complete project, which is pretty much not Minimal :(

Comment: @MartynA Well, as I stated in the topic, this exact line is working in the other part of program, I used debugger to check used variable values - they are the same. The problem is that it is not only the showmessage not adding static string to the menuMain.player. It is also memo does the same. My programming knowledge ends at that point, this means I have to get help, here is surely the best place :) btw I had exact same problem on my other project, but is mystically disappeared after a week break from it. Magic...

Comment: @RobKennedy the exact value of buffer string (buffer = menuMain.player[2] + ' ready!'): 'Player'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0' ready!'

Comment: Excellent information. It's enough by which someone can give a definite answer. Also, you've learned to check the debugger.

Comment: @RobKennedy I have always used shomessage() to check variable values, I thought it was more convenient, now I see how much of a fool I was, thank you ;)

Comment: I was only challenging your belief that " this is a compiler glitch".

Comment: `#0`character is special in very many cases, you should not have in in the middle of your string. It's a glitch in your data causes this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the exact value of buffer string (buffer = menuMain.player[2] + ' ready!'): 'Player'#0#0#0#0#0#0#0#0' ready!'

The problem is the embedded null characters (the `#0`). Those characters act as string terminators, which means the string stops being processed at that point for most WinAPI functions, including those that output or paint text. When the first `#0` is found, the string is considered to have ended.

You can test this easily enough yourself, with code something like this:

```
var
  TestStr: string;
begin
  TestStr := 'This is a test';
  ShowMessage(TestStr);          // Outputs This is a test
  TestStr[5] := #0;
  ShowMessage(TestStr);          // Outputs This
end;
```

The remaining question, of course, is how did you end up with those embedded nulls in the first place? Since you've not posted the code that populates `menuMain.player`, it's impossible to say, but that's that's the area you need to inspect, because string array elements in Delphi do not contain nulls on their own. You can also check that yourself:

```
var
  TestArr: array[1..2] of string;
begin
  TestArr[1] := 'Player one';
  TestArr[2] := 'Player two';
  ShowMessage(TestArr[1] + ' defeated ' + TestArr[2]);
end;
```

So the answer to your question

> Now the tough part for me, is that me being dumb, or this is indeed a glitch?

It's a glitch, but the glitch is somewhere in your code. It's not a glitch in Delphi or its strings.

Comment: That you for answer! When I was going through a code I came up with a possible solution, but I need confirmation. I receive menuMain.player[2] from TCustomWinSocket, but in this component function SentText (Which I use) uses AnsiString type, is there any possible way that conversion from AnsiString to regular string causes #0 corruption? Thanks again :)

Comment: No, AnsiString to *regular string* does not add #0 characters either. I can't tell you what's wrong with your use of TCustomWinSocket, because I can't see that code (and that would be a totally different issue, which you should ask about in a new question).

Comment: oh, I found problem and it was indeed my stupidity. I used input string to get menuMain.player[2] symbol-by-symbol (example buf[1] := input[16];). I have not checked if input[i] <> #0 on writing of symbol. I will add solution to the question body. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No, do not add that solution to the question body, because it's not part of this question. As I said before, that's a different issue. I've answered the question you asked here.